# How would I be able to append an item to a specific array on a Parse Server?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-server

I am trying to create a comments section for my app that allows user to comment on a post. I'm currently using Parse, and I had attempted to create a row full of arrays. Each row would contain an array, that held the comments for a particular post. I am currently confused as to how I would be able to access then update the array at the given row. I've been reading the Parse documentation and guides, but haven't been able to figure this out yet. My code is below and the screenshot for my Parse page/layout is below as well.  I'd appreciate it if anybody could help me out or even just recommend a better way for me to deal with user comments for a particular post.

Please note that the 'Answers' are the 'Commments'.

In the case below, Test and Dog represent the comments on one post and Cat and Meow represent the comments on another post.

NOTE: Below, comments is an array of arrays.

```
var post = PFObject(className: "Posts")

        var query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")

        query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in


            if let posts = objects {


                for object in posts{


                    if let post = object as? PFObject {

                        if let Answers = post["Answers"] {

                            self.comments.append(Answers as! [String])

                            print(post["Answers"])
                        }

                    }

                }





                self.comments[self.indexPathNum].append(self.answerTextView.text)

                post["Answers"] = self.comments



                    post.saveInBackground(block: { (success, error) in
                        if error != nil {

                            print("error")

                        }else {
                            print("Success")
                        }
                    })

                }









        })
```

Comment: How do you know which post you are trying to append a comment to?  It looks like all you are doing there is looking in the Posts table and then for every row in the table it looks like you are trying to append your Answers column to your self.comments variable.  You won't be able to update the Answers column that way as the self.comments array is just that an array and does not hold reference to the objectId of each post.  Why not just update the Answers array for a given post when the comment is made so you don't have to maintain an array?

Comment: Hey Pippo, thanks for the comment. Originally, I was trying to download the whole answers column for my server and store that it one nested array. I would then access each set of comments based on the 'indexPath.row'. How would I be able to implement your solution and only access one 'set' of comments? Thanks again!

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what is going on in your table view or how the posts work. but i gather that each row of the tableview is a specific post?  you would need to get the objectId of that post then append the comments